# Как подключить два файла из разных папок Python

Tags: python, библиотеки

Нужно подключить две разных библиотеки из разных мест (причем папка flask находится в одной папке с файлом .py).

Пытаюсь выполнить такой код:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask, jsonify
#!/usr/bin/python
import psycopg2
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
ImportError: No module named psycopg2
```

Но по отдельности все работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю такое решение:

```py
""" Для относительного импорта """
from flask.bin.python import Flask, jsonify

""" Для абсолютного импорта """
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/bin/python')

import psycopg2
```

Что здесь происходит:

1. Для импорта по пути, начинающемуся с текущей папки, можно использовать названия папок через точку. Если начало не в текущей папке, а на несколько уровней выше, необходимо в начале поставить соответствующее кол-во точек (подробнее в статье по ссылке в конце ответа).
2. Для импорта из любого расположения его необходимо сначала занести в `sys.path`, (в котором python вообще ищет всё, что импортируется), а потом уже импортировать в обычном режиме.

Много интересного про импорт модулей можно прочитать [здесь](https://tproger.ru/translations/guide-into-python-imports/).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96601/discussion-on-answer-by-v-mor--------python).

Comment: Нужно было просто правильный путь к psycopg2

Comment: @Vlad В итоге Вашим или моим способом заработало?

Comment: @V-Mor, да, первое - это я подключил flask через '#!flask/bin/python', а второе описал выше